# How do I get Google Sheets (Google Finance) to show the what date the lowest stock price was within a date range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, google-finance

Currently I have the following formula:

```
=MIN(INDEX(GOOGLEFINANCE(B2, "low",DATE(2020,2,19),TODAY()),0,2))
```

This gives me the lowest price for my stock but I want to know what date this lowest price was as well. 
Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=QUERY(GOOGLEFINANCE(B2, "low", DATE(2020, 2, 19), TODAY()),
 "order by Col2 limit 1 offset 1", 0)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Excellent, thank you!
To find the HIGHEST price, only change 2 parameters: "low" to "high", obviously, and add " desc" after "order by Col2"